# call transition.to with id: corona SDK

Tags: android, transition, coronasdk, objectid

In one of my corona apps, I've to apply transition to objects with certain `id`. How can I do this?

```
local ball = display.newImage("ball.png") 
   -- sample, actually there are random no. of balls created at an instant.
ball.id = "ball_id"

transition.to(ball,{time=200,x=400})
   -- here, instead of ball, i need to call all objects(if any) with id="ball_id"
```

Any advice is appreciable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store all your objects in a table.
This solution will work even if you will remove some objects from **balls** table.
It works because I used ipairs.
More info: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial

```
local balls = {}

local function createRandonBall( id )
    local ball = display.newImage("ball.png") 
    ball.id = id

    balls[#balls + 1] = ball
end

local function animateBall(id)

    for i, object in ipairs(balls) do
        if(object.id == id) then
            transition.to(object, {time=200,x=400} )
        end
    end

end


animateBall("ball_id")  //call all objects(if any) with id="ball_id"
```